# Limit behavior of Poisson's process near zero

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, poisson-process

If $N(t)$ is a Poisson process how to say that $\lim\limits_{t\to 0} \frac{N(t)}{t} = 0$  (convergence in probability). Probably I have to use properties of Poisson process, but I have any ideas. Any hints?

Comment: Can you estimate $P(N(t)>\epsilon t)$ for small $t$?

Comment: @HartoSaarinen as $t\to \infty$ IIRC, but that’s not the limiting value here.

Comment: $P(N(t)>k$ is the same that $P(S_{k-1}<t,S_{k}\geq  t)$, but I think that this way is not good. I can't estimate $P(N(t)>\varepsilon t) $for  small $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show that for each fixed $\epsilon>0$, that $\lim_{t\to0}P(N(t)>\epsilon t)=0$.

But $N(t)$ is Poisson with expectation $t$, and hence non-negative integer valued.  So if $t\epsilon<1$, the event $[N(t)>\epsilon t]$ is the complement of the event  $[N(t)=0]$, and so $$P(N(t)>\epsilon t)=1-P(N(t)=0)=1-\exp(-t) ,$$ and its limit as $t\to0$ is $0$.

Comment: I have a questions. 

From definition of convergence in propabiblity:
$X_{n}\xrightarrow{p} X$ means that $\forall \varepsilon>0 \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty} P(|X_n-X|<\varepsilon)=0$. In our situation we have
$$\lim\limits_{t\to \infty} N(t)>\varepsilon t$$ (after modifications). Why not $t \rightarrow 0$ instead of $t \rightarrow  \infty$.Probably I don't undestrand definition.

Comment: The original problem asked for $t\to0$ convergence.  So that's what I measured.